# Filling axis only when value of another one changes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot like this:

[image]

How can I make the date axis to be visible only for unique Y axis values? My code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from datetime import datetime

unibet_spec_id = 1007732543
frame = pandas.read_csv('result.csv')
ids = frame.index[frame['unibet_id'] == unibet_spec_id].tolist()
mask = frame['id'].isin(ids)
data_1 = frame.loc[mask]['sportradar_1'].tolist()
data_time = frame.loc[mask]['sportradar_timestamp'].tolist()

data_time = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(stmp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for stmp in data_time]

plt.plot(data_time, data_1)
plt.savefig('name')
```

Thanks a lot
P.S. I need something like this, marked the places for dates
[image]

Comment: Why don't you create and set up four ticks and four ticks for the changed values?

Comment: @r-beginners I am not really familiar with matplotlib, could you please explain?

Comment: For example, you can use set the tick labels to ['2021-12-03','','','','','2021-12-07,'2021-12-08','','',...]. Create the xticklabels